# Is there such a thing as a convex polytope defined over a mixed-variable space: $\mathbb{Z}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: polytopes, convex-hulls

I am currently learning about polytopes and I have reached the stage of *convex polytopes*. Wiki says that a

> convex polytope is a special case of a polytope, having the additional property that it is also a convex set contained in the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space
> $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

then we go to the definition of a convex set:

> In geometry, a subset of a Euclidean space, or more generally an affine space over the reals, is convex if, given any two points in the subset, the subset contains the whole line segment that joins them

Now as the title of this question says, I am wondering if we can define a convex polytope on the mixed-integer space $\mathbb{Z}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

I believe the answer is 'no' because the integer-set does not have the convex set property required of a convex polytope. But I am still very much a novice in this area so wanted to reach out to more knowledgeable people to see if there is in fact a version (or some other object) over the mixed space.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Following the current fad with LLMs, this is what ChatGPT gives as answer to this question.

---

Mathematically, a convex polytope in $\mathbb{Z}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined as follows:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+n) \times (m+n)}$ be a matrix, and $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ be a vector. Then the convex polytope can be defined as:

$$P = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax + By \leq \mathbf{b}\},$$

where $x \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ represents the integer coordinates, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ represents the real coordinates, and $A$, $B$, and $\mathbf{b}$ define the linear inequalities that the points must satisfy to belong to the polytope.

---

But then I wonder, do you need linear inequalities do define this type of convex polytope? That seems odd.

Comment: You seem to be aware that Chat-GPT's definition is wrong in that set it defines isn't convex and that there is in fact no such thing as a convex polytope on $Z^{m} \times R^{n}$.   Do you have some remaining question about this?

Comment: Well I suppose I just wanted confirmation of what you have succinctly put that "set it defines isn't convex". Do you know what other way one can formally describe a mixed-integer space as defined above, if not with convex polytopes?

Comment: There is a very large literature on  the convex hull of the MILP solutions which is a convex polytope.  This isn’t what you have asked for, but it might be of interest.  I’d encourage you to rethink your question.

Comment: That's grand, thanks.